# Mapping Over Either

Tags: haskell

Why doesn't the case with `(-1)` work here:

```
λ> (+1) <$> Right 10
Right 11
Prelude
λ> (-1) <$> Right 10

<interactive>:22:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b a1. (Num (a -> b), Num a) => Either a1 b
Prelude
λ> (*1) <$> Right 10
Right 10
Prelude
λ> (/1) <$> Right 10
Right 10.0
Prelude
λ>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's interpreting `(-1)` as `-1` rather than `((-) 1)`

Try `((-) 1) <$> Right 10`

Comment: Yep that works. But what if I wanted to do 10 - 1, how do I get that to work?

Comment: You could use `flip` or write the lambda out. There's also `subtract`, as linked in the dup question